# Clickable div with base64 image background

Tags: css, meteor

I have this div with a base64 image background and set the div width to 40x40 pixels, which is also the original size of the image. I want the entire div to be clickable but only about a 10px x 10px area actually is.

```
<template name="print">
 <div style="display:inline-block; margin-left:705px; margin-top:40px;min-width:40px; min-height:40px; cursor:pointer; background-image:url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhK...w==);" id="printSelect" >
 </div>
</template>

Template.print.events({
 'click #printSelect': function(theEvent, theTemplate) {
    // popup a list of available reports
    theTemplate.find("#reportSel").style.display = "inline";
 }
})
```

Any idea hot to get the entire div to be clickable?

Comment: What do you mean by clickable? Is there a JavaScript event that goes along with this HTML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `div` has 40px `margin` which is not added to the div's space. Try using `width` and `height` or `padding` instead, so the space is added to your div - and the clickable area.

Comment: That did it! `padding-top:40px;width:40px; height:40px;`